# 2 oneOf in json schema: 1 required 1 optional

Tags: json, schema, field, option-type

I have a json schema that works when I use 2 oneOf for 2 choices between required fields. But I don't know how to do the same with optional fields.

My schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "c": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "d": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "e": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": ["a"],
  "oneOf": [
    {"required": ["b"]},
    {"required": ["c"]}
  ],
  "oneOf": [
    {"required": ["d"]},
    {"required": ["e"]}
  ]
}
```

How can I transform to make d and e optional (while never having both at once)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a [gist with my solution](http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json?gist=9ecd0953e08f5b7e55300f3920f79a35), shown in http://jsonschemalint.com. (Very handy tool!)

Properties `d` and `e` are already defined, and allowed (but not required) in any combination.  To make these two properties mutually exclusive, we say that the instance must `not` match a schema that has both properties:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "a": {"type": "number"},
    "b": {"type": "number"},
    "c": {"type": "number"},
    "d": {"type": "number"},
    "e": {"type": "number"}
  },
  "required": ["a"],
  "oneOf": [
      {"required": ["b"]},
      {"required": ["c"]}
    ],
  "not" : {"required" : ["d","e"]}
}
```

This works nicely, but it starts getting messy if you have more than two properties in your mutually exclusive group.  For example, if we wanted to add property `f` and make it mutually exclusive with respect to `d` and `e`, we'd have to disallow three distinct combinations:

```
  "not" : {
    "anyOf"{
      {"required" : ["d","e"]},
      {"required" : ["d","f"]},
      {"required" : ["e","f"]},
    }
  }
```

Here's an alternative that's more verbose, but scales up to larger sets of mutually exclusive properties:

```
  "oneOf" : [
    {"required" : ["d"]},
    {"required" : ["e"]},
    {"required" : ["f"]},
    {
      "not" : {
        "anyOf" : [
          {"required" : ["d"]},
          {"required" : ["e"]},
          {"required" : ["f"]}
        ]
      }  
    }
  ]
```

Each property added to the group requires exactly two lines.

Since our schema now has two `oneOf` constraints, we need to combine them using `allOf`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "a": {"type": "number"},
    "b": {"type": "number"},
    "c": {"type": "number"},
    "d": {"type": "number"},
    "e": {"type": "number"},
    "f": {"type": "number"}
  },
  "required": ["a"],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
          {"required": ["b"]},
          {"required": ["c"]}
        ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf" : [
        {"required" : ["d"]},
        {"required" : ["e"]},
        {"required" : ["f"]},
        {
          "not" : {
            "anyOf" : [
              {"required" : ["d"]},
              {"required" : ["e"]},
              {"required" : ["f"]}
            ]
          }  
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With your solution,  `{"a": 1, "b":1}` or  `{"a": 1, "c":1}` are not valid but I need them. How can I adapt for my case?

Comment: Just updated my example and explanation to show the solution.  Good catch!

Comment: lovelace63, after you accepted my answer, I  found a much cleaner solution. This one doesn't require repeating the list of optional properties, so it's easier to maintain. It also allows makes it easier to create multiple, independent sets of mutually exclusive properties, either required or optional.  Please take a look and let me know if you see any problems with this.